# How to find row index which contains given string? Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to upgrade my scrip to analyze data. Instead of manualy checking row number to be header line i need to find the index row that contains specific string. Now i read csv directly to pandas dataframe with headerline defined like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('sensor_1.csv', sep=',', header=101)
```

How to read csv and find line with "Scan Number" text and put this variable to header definition?

I tried this:

```
FileList = (glob.glob("sensor_1.csv"))
for FileToProcess in FileList:
        with open(FileToProcess) as readfile:
            for cnt,line in enumerate(readfile):
                if "Scan Number" in line:
                    cnt
        readfile.close

df1 = pd.read_csv('sensor_1.csv', sep=',', header= cnt)
```

But this gives highest index and error at the end :/
Could you please help?

Thanks
Paulina

Comment: (1) The line "cnt" does nothing. (2) The line "readfile.close" does nothing because "close" is not called and is unnecessary because the file is closed automatically when with-block is exited. You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: @Paulina If you do not specify a header, the file is read without errors?

Comment: @inquirer totally without "header = ..." there is error because lines above are not read as dataframe.

Comment: @Paulina i.e. tried this:      df1 = pd.read_csv('sensor_1.csv', sep=',')

Comment: @Paulina try the code i answered you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fille_ =  open('sensor_1.csv', 'r')
lines = fille_.readlines()
cnt = 0
for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    if lines[i].find('Scan Number') !=-1:
        cnt = i
        break
        
print(cnt)
```

When the search phrase is found in the string, the loop will print the index of the string and the loop will stop.

Comment: This works fine! Thanks. And now incorporated cnt variable into header and im done with this part! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you dont need to use globe library
it's use for listing files inside a directory ... but you have the filename already

when you use 'with' command you don't need to close file too . it'll be
closed after indention

try this

```
import pandas as pd , csv

rownumber_list = []
with open("Salary_Data.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    for cnt,line in enumerate(csvreader):
        if "Scan Number" in line:
            rownumber_list.append(cnt)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(rownumber_list , columns=['row_number'])
```